HTTP Server not accessible from intranet
We have a cable network and a few static IPs from the ISP. A server is connected to the cable modem (also as a router) and has a static IP assigned. An HTTP service is running on the server. Everything works pretty well, we can access the HTTP service from WAN.
There is an office router plugged into the same cable modem. Devices connected to this router can access the internet without any issue, but they cannot access our HTTP service. However, they can successfully ping the server.
What could be the problem here?


what is the error you receive in the browser and the browser dev tools Network tab?

@FrankThomas the good old ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT, which I suppose means that it cannot connect at all

yeah, that can mean a complete failure to connect. I'd start with powershell's test-netconnection to test connectivity to the TCP port on the server, and if it fails, start checking firewalls on the office router and the server. you should probably also confirm that the server is listening on the port on the 0.0.0.0 rather than the LAN ip. you can check the "local address" from netstat -abo | findstr LISTEN to confirm. also confirm that if the app has any IP allow list, that the office router LAN is on it.

How do you connect to the HTTP service, by IP or by host.domain ? Do computers connected to the offce router network have their own address space/subnet ?

@FrankThomas test-connection fails as expected. The HTTP service itself is definitely fine becuse we can access it with an external computer without any issue. I also tried to turn off the firewall on the office router, did not work either. In fact I've done as many regular checks as I could, all ended up with no clue except that we know there must be something wrong with the office router - but how?

@Silbee we connect by IP. Computers connected to the office router are all in the router's subnet.

did you check what IP address the application is listening on on the server? if its set to listen just on the local IP, not 0.0.0.0, the os will only allow access to the port from clients in that IP subnet. that would explain all the symptoms, so worth a check. look at the local address column when you run netstat -abo | findstr LISTEN

oh btw, that netstat command is for windows, and you havent mentioned what OS the server is running. if its linux use (as root/sudo) netstat -ntlup | grep LISTEN. the local address will be listed first (before the remote address, but that will always be 0.0.0.0 because its a listening port). the last token on each line will be the PIID and name of the process that owns that port.

@FrankThomas the HTTP service is listening on 0.0.0.0 (otherwise it can't be accessed by the external network).

@Silbee we also tried to connect by domain name but it does not work either. Also I should mention that it's not only the HTTP service, but (apparently) anything that requires a TCP connection does not work. For example, we can't SSH to that server by its static IP.

It turned out to be the office router's problem. We replaced the router with an H3C one and everything now works like a charm!

It turned out to be the office router's problem. We replaced the router with an H3C one and everything now works like a charm!
